# Custom Annotation with GeneratedValue and GenericGenerator in Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

How to create a custom annotation with the following in Hibernate

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = “UUID”)
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = “UUID”,
        strategy = “org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator”,
    )
    @Column(name = “id”, updatable = false, nullable = false)
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Create a custom generator?

Comment: I would like to create a new annotation comprising of all the annotations mentioned above.